# What year is this Specialized Stumpjumper FSR?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I'm interested in buying this, but was curious as to what year the frame is? Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you look up what kind of rear shock it has or other components, you're likely able to find out.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I don't believe it's a Stumpjumper, I think it is a [2001  Specialized  S-Works FSR XC](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2001&brand=Specialized&model=S-Works+FSR+XC).

Comment: Maybe a bit later model - this one has Discs, the 2001 was V Brakes.

Comment: Good catch, I spent too much time looking at paint jobs!

Comment: Looks like discs came out in 2002, this colour was available 2002 but with V's, but shock is Reba, not Fox Float.  Could be a non-standard build for a specific chain or non original (upgraded shocks and replace rear triangle) to get disc upgrade. Regardless, a very nice bike and nice condition for its age.

Comment: Could be.  Definitely 2003 or earlier, the frame design was different in 2004.  Might be a one off color or something as well.  Specialized has something of a history with unlisted color options.

Comment: It's frame is 2003 or earlier but Reba didn't exist till 2005 so a user upgrade on the forks and probably the brakes too

Comment: I think it's more complicated. Definitely the 2001 s-works front triangle. There were disc fsrs in 2002, so probably a changed out rear triangle, was there a recall? Or upgrade offered. 2005 fork for disc conversion also. 10 speed conversion and new Deore RD.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a 2003 Stumpjumper FSR XC disc. It has aftermarket parts like the Deore rear derailleur (stock was Shimano 9s XT), RockShox Reba fork (stock was 100mm Manitou Super Axle). The crankset---which looks gorgeous with the color scheme of this bike-- is not the stock  Specialized Strong Arm II, I don't believe.

Observations that made me decide on model year '03 include the hole in the seat post support structure, what appears to be a Fox FLOAT RL for rear suspension, and color scheme, none of which are present on an '02 Stumpy FSR XC.  The '02 and '03 models share nearly identical frame characteristics like M4 tubing, the curved and offset seat tube, Horst link,  type and placement of the rear shock.  Componentry is fairly identical sharing the same Shimano M525 disc brake system, 9s Deore LX shifters and front der, 11-32t cassette.  '02 models sported XTR (M952) rear ders where '03 got XT.  Another element when comparing the stock-equipped models is the front fork where the RockShox Duke XC was replaced by a Manitou in '03. In 2004, many changes are evident to the frame design that are absent here.

Nearly 20 years old, my '02 Stumpjumper, rides like a dream with the original rear Fox FLOAT R rear shock paired with an '07 Fox FLOAT RL fork.  I modernized the drivetrain to Shimano Deore 2x10 (34/24t front, 11-36t cassette, Hollowtech2 cranks), clutched Deore rear der, XT front der,  SLX shifters, and Deore disc brakes (BR/BL M596). Cockpit, hubs and rims are the OE.  Despite the age and mere 26" wheels, it is FAST and just rocks the single track.